# Invoking searchable activity in Android?

Tags: java, android, searchable

I'm following http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html to create a searchable activity for my app.

SearchableActivity.java

```
package com.xxxx.xx;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.xxxx.xx;

public class SearchableActivity extends ListActivity {
protected SQLiteDatabase db;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search);

    // Get the intent, verify the action and get the query
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
      String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
      doMySearch(query);
    }
}




public List<String> doMySearch(String query) {
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

Cursor c = db.query(
        "employee", 
        new String[] { "_id" }, // The column you want as a result of the Query
        "firstName like '%?%' OR lastName like '%?%' OR officePhone like '%?%'", // The where-Clause of the statement with placeholders (?)
        new String[] { query, query, query }, // One String for every Placeholder-? in the where-Clause
        null, // if you like a order by put it here
        null, // group by here
        null  // having here
        );
while (c.moveToNext()) {
    result.add(c.getString(0));
}
c.close();
return result;
}
}
```

/res/xml/searchable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_label"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint" >
</searchable>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.xxxx.xx"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />      
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                   android:value="com.xxxx.xx.SearchableActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.xxxx.xx.TestList"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.xxxx.xx.SearchableActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                   android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.xxxx.xx.TestDetails"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.xxxx.xx.TestList">
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                       android:value="com.xxxx.xx.SearchableActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.xxxx.xx.DirectReports"></activity>
    </application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="14"/>
```

I have added all these but the device SEARCH button is not opening the search dialog. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about this, but it might be because you declare your application's package as `package="com.xxxxxxx.tests"`, but in all of your activity references you use `samples.xxxxxxxxx.SearchableActivity`. Try updating your app package name to `"samples.xxxxx"` and see if that fixes it. Also, in your code you have your package declared as `package com.xxxx.xx;`. So, make up your mind and make all of the references consistent.

Comment: I wasn't able to figure out what was wrong with that package. I had to create a new one. Its all working fine now. Thanks.